# C write() function sending 2 bytes hexadecimal

Tags: c, linux

I'm working with TCP sockets. I'm sending data to the open socket using the write function.

write(Socket_Fd, "test", 4);

That works. But when I do it this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct LANC
{
 BYTE START;
 BYTE END;

} LCODE;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

LCODE COMMAND;
COMMAND.START = 0x28;
COMMAND.END = 0x06;

short value = (COMMAND.START << 8) | COMMAND.END;

write(socket_FD, value, sizeof(value);

return 0;
}
```

when I check the size of the value I get 2 bytes which is correct since i combined 0x28 and 0x06. So doing a printf.

```
printf("%x\n", value);

output is: 2806 which is correct.

printf("%d\n", sizeof(value);

output is: 2 bytes which is correct.
```

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to write the hexadecimal to the open socket using write. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your description of your problem is not clear.  In your example code, `socket_FD` is not a valid socket handle so I presume this isn't your real code.  Can you update your question to show real code please?  A better description that "I get an error" would be helpful too.

Comment: `I'm getting an error when I'm trying to write the hexadecimal to the open socket using write. What am I doing wrong?` You are *not* showing the failing code; only the code that works.

Comment: @simonc, Yes this is not the real code I just made it but it's the portion of the full code I'm getting error, I don't have the full code right now since I'm at home and the code is at the office. The error I'm getting is with write function. e.g passing a value which is an int type to write function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're committing two disgusting errors in one line (how does it even compile?). You're passing an integer (value) to `write()` where it expects a pointer (that won't compile, you're trying to deceive us about your code). Secondly, you're doing something that's endian-dependant, that is, on different processors you'll get different results depending on whether the high-byte of "value" comes first or second in memory.

Solution:

```
unsigned char value[2] = {COMMAND.START, COMMAND.END};

write(socket_FD, value, sizeof(value));
```

Comment: Also, please please please check the return value of `write()`.

Comment: Yes sorry about the bad code it's just a dummy sample code I made from scratch not the real code. And also yes i forgot to mention that it won't compile since i'm getting error with regards to write function.

Comment: So your actual code at home doesn't even compile? Fix that before asking any questions. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) soon, and always make an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) as that helps people help you.